# Help needed sourcing gear/track material for stepper motor

Tags: tracks

I am completely new to robotics and engineering and it looks as though I have stumbled at the first hurdle when building a prototype.

I am trying to build a curved track upon which a motorised carriage can run. I know that I need a stepper motor and a cog, however for the tracks I can't find anything similar to the picture below:

[image: Curved track]

The youtube video is as follows: [Lumia 640XL mach3 step motor curve motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsJiL6Uod1M)

There is a slight difference in that I need straight sections and 90-degree bends for the tracks, rather than a circle.

Does anyone know what these sections are called, as "tracks" and "runners" doesn't yield anything.

Comment: google `rack and pinion`

Comment: hi @jsotola I did that, along with `curved rack pinion`, but absolutely nothing that resembles this.

Comment: does it have to be transparent? ... you could use a toothed belt that is attached to the side of the track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular part is called a [ring gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starter_ring_gear), but you're probably not going to find one because the item in your picture is almost certainly custom-made.

The particular article I linked is for engine starter motors, so it has *external* teeth, but there are internally-toothed ring gears, too.

What you're describing, beyond the picture, *does* sound like a kind of modular track system, but I'm unaware of any off-the-shelf solutions. You might have luck with [timing belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_belt_(camshaft)) (or [toothed belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toothed_belt)), but it would probably be easier to get parts custom-fabricated to your exact specification than to try to cobble something together from miscellaneous parts.

There seems to be a good number of off-the-shelf small-scale timing belts [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JKT5BZQ) intended for 3D printers, though. Not affiliated with or recommending the Amazon link, just wanted to give an example.

Comment: thanks for that Chuck! Looks like I'll have to go down the custom route for this project, as you suggested.

Comment: @luke_mclachlan yeah, hate to say it. Looks like the ring gear in your picture is made out of polycarbonate or acrylic sheet. Fortunately, if that's good enough for you strength-wise, then it shouldn't be super expensive to have machined. If there's a maker space near you then you might be able to go cut the parts yourself with a laser cutter!

Comment: Well Chuck it's amazing you mention it because I found a maker hub by chance today, smack bang in the middle of stockholm. For prototyping it's perfect.